# Input de dados pelo Python no SQLExpress

Tags: mysql, python, pyodbc

Estou começando um projeto em que resumidamente, eu estou pensando em fazer o insert de dados no SQL pelo python atraves de um input ao usuario.

Eu ja consegui fazer a conexão entre o SQL e o Python pelo pyodbc, ja criei o banco, fiz insert pelas linhas do programa e tal.

Mas o que eu realmente quero, é fazer o input desses dados como usuario. Criar um programinha que quando executado, faz uma sequencia de perguntas sendo que cada resposta será armazenada e inserida em cada coluna dessa tabela.

Estou recorrendo ao stack pois cansei de pesquisar sobre isso no youtube e na documentação, e nao
achei nada sobre.

Obrigado

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection='yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',server = 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' , database = 'teste')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO testando (id, nome, qtd)
                VALUES
                (1,'Mesa',2),
                (2,'Celular',1)
                ''')
cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

olha, **eu nunca trabalhei com o pyodbc** mas se o funcionamento dele for semelhante ao do mysql-connector ou ao do sqlite3 talvez isso funcione...

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM testando")

tabela = cursor.fechall()
```

aí (se funcionar), ele deve retornar uma lista de tuplas

ex:

`[(1, "mesa", 2), (2, celular, 1)]`

Espero que funcione....